# Django REST: Problem with AUTH_USER_MODEL importing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm following [this tutorial](https://krakensystems.co/blog/2020/custom-users-using-django-rest-framework) and trying to create custom user for REST-API.

**settings.py:**

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # blah blah
    'courses',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'courses.CustomUser'
```

I have

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'courses.CustomUser' that has not been installed

**project tree:**

```
- django-project
    - courses
        - models.py
```

**models.py:**

```py
class CurstomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = None

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [USERNAME_FIELD, 'first_name', 'last_name']

    role = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=UserRole.choices, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

What's the problem? It seems I've set up `AUTH_USER_MODEL` correct way

Comment: typo in Cu_r_stomUser?

Comment: AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'courses.CurstomUser'

Comment: 'r' for CurstomUser dropped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the settings.py file like

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'courses.CurstomUser'
```